# Fire Ajax call in Durandal.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, durandal

I would like to refresh data on a page based on data that's typed in an input tag. I am using Durandal.js.

Other than using  composition.addBinding  and binding to jQuery, is there any other way ( more elegant ) to do this ? maybe using Knockout ?

I want an ajax call to fire when I edit search_for

My JS is like this :

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'moment'], function (http, app, ko, moment) {
//Note: This module exports an object.
//That means that every module that "requires" it will get the same object instance.
//If you wish to be able to create multiple instances, instead export a function.
//See the "welcome" module for an example of function export.

return {
    start_date: ko.observable(""),
    end_date: ko.observable(""),
    search_for: ko.observable(""),
    records_per_page: ko.observable(""),
    records: ko.observableArray([]),
    getShippersData: function() {
         ....
    }
```

Thanks all

Comment: Can you post code snippet? I might be able to help you.

Comment: My JS file is something like this :

Comment: Edit your question and add your JS snippet :-)

Comment: I have added an answer, you can take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of knockout subscription here.

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'moment'], function (http, app, ko, moment) {
//Note: This module exports an object.
//That means that every module that "requires" it will get the same object instance.
//If you wish to be able to create multiple instances, instead export a function.
//See the "welcome" module for an example of function export.

var self = this;
self.search_for = ko.observable(""); // can make use of rateLimit extender here to avoid frequent ajax calls.

search_for.subscribe(function(searchTerm){
    //make use of searchTerm i.e. search_for variable to make ajax call.
   //Whenever you change value of search_for, this method will invoke
})

return {
    start_date: ko.observable(""),
    end_date: ko.observable(""),
    search_for: search_for,

    records_per_page: ko.observable(""),
    records: ko.observableArray([]),
    getShippersData: function() {
         ....
    }
```

Subscription will be invoked as soon as you change something in search_for variable. You can limit the occurance by setting throttle on change tracking using "rate limiter" (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html)

`self.search_for = ko.observable("").extend({ rateLimit : 500 })`

**rateLimit** causes an observable to suppress and delay change notifications for a specified period of time instead of notifying the change immediately

Comment: Thank you .. That was brilliant. I ended up doubling my JavaScript knowledge :)